# Serilog implementation for layered architecture using .Net framework

Tags: .net, serilog

I have a layered architecture(UI, BL, Serive, DAL) and want to use Serilog as my logging framework.  I'm trying to decide the best way to implement it.  I'd ideally like to have a separate project that setups up Serilog and then is referenced by all other projects that require logging.  However, each project should write to it's own log file.  I'm not sure if this is the best(or even possible) way to implement logging, and since I can't really find any good documentation around this I thought I'd ask the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like how you manage DI config in a system: you don't give each subsystem carte-blanche control.

The Composition Root for a given app should own the logging config for an app.

It can call out to shared helpers (i.e. Enrichers) to effect that config, and that can be shared.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do you know of any examples that are out there?  I'm having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: I mean in the ConfigureServices and/or other startup logic - I'd search `aspnet startup initialize logging` or similar (you havent said much about what kind of app you have) depending on what sort of host apps you have